# Apache Airflow Dependencies, what if task are parallel?

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

Let's say that we have 3 task `A,B,C`  that are executed in order `A>>B>>C`.
I'm using Apache Airflow and creating a DAG that will use these 3 tasks.

I would have to write (where task A is ta, task B is tb, task C is tc) :

```
ta>>tb>>tc
```

**But what if after A it would go to B and C that are 2 parallel tasks ?**
**How would I have to write the dependencies ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is as below

```
ta >> tb
ta >> tc
```

or

```
ta >> [tb, tc]
```

This will make `B` & `C` parallel after `A`

More info can found here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#bitshift-composition